# Similar Products with bitwise

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following tables.

[image]

So one product can have one category, one category can have n genres.(Products-> Genre Column data 6 ( 2 + 4), 132 (128 + 4) like that).

So my question is; i want to do find similar products for one product with using bitwise genres. Is that possible with sql query (or stored procedure)?

I never do something like that before, so i need help about it.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show a few rows of sample data and desired results?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/2hn60y 35 is mean Drama(2),Fantasy(32),Horror(1) so when i select this product, query must find which include drama products or fantasy products or horror products.

Comment: I don't really follow your schema here. Is `Products.Genre` just a non normalised version of what you can already get from `Products -> Category -> Genre`. In any event bitwise manipulation is severely limited in TSQL. Especially if you have more than 32 genres.

Comment: And to expand on the limitations mentions by @MartinSmith - it's also going to hurt performance on lookup.

Comment: there's not much genre it will be no over 32. But what your suggestion about genres just a relation table ? or something better ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done it.

with that i get product genres

```
(Select ((SELECT Genre from Products where ID = 159) & ID) as ID from genres where CategoryID = 13)
```

after that, i need reach products so i join it and filter with

```
t.ID <> 0 and (p.Genre & t.ID) = t.ID and CategoryID = 13
```

and result !

```
Select distinct p.* from (Select ((SELECT Genre from Products where ID = 159) & ID) as ID from genres where CategoryID = 13) as t inner join products as p on t.ID <> 0 and (p.Genre & t.ID) = t.ID and CategoryID = 13
```

with that query give me what i want !

thanks for replys.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use [bitwise `&` operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174965.aspx):

```
select products.genres, genre.Id from 
products inner join genre 
on products.genres & genre.Id > 0 
order by products.genres, genre.Id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1b450/1)